# split values among names in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I've a dateframe 1

```
          Place     
  0       New York
  1       Los Angeles 1 
  2       Los Angeles- 2 
  3       Dallas -1
  4       Dallas - 2
  5       Dallas3
```

dataframe 2

```
Place          target    value1     value2
New York        1000       a          b
Los Angeles     1500       c          d
Dallas 1        2000       e          f
```

Desired dataframe

```
Place          target       value1     value2
New York        1000           a           b
Los Angeles 1   750            c           d
Los Angeles- 2  750            c           d
Dallas -1       666.6          e           f
Dallas - 2      666.6          e           f
Dallas3         666.6          e           f
```

**Explanation:** We have to merge dataframe1 and dateframe2 on 'place'. We have 1 New york, 2 Los Angeles, 3 Dallas in dataframe1, but we have only ones in dateframe2. So we split the target based on the count of places (only names, not numbers) in df1 and assign value1 and value2 to respective place.

Is there any way to consider all the spell check, whitespaces, special characters using regex and obtain the desired dataframe?

Comment: Good question. What have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: @JoeFerndz I have taken the count of places in df1 and using that I'm replicating the rows of respective places in df2. And for my work, I'm extracting it to csv and trying to edit the name accordingly which is not an acceptable and optimal solution in python. So looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact solution:

```
def extract_city(col):
    return col.str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)')[0]

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=extract_city(df1['Place']), right_on=extract_city(df2['Place']))

df = df.drop(['key_0', 'Place_y'], axis=1).rename({'Place_x' : 'Place'}, axis=1)

df['Target'] /= df.groupby(extract_city(df['Place']))['Place'].transform('count')

df
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method to do thing this will be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Place':['New York','Los Angeles 1','Los Angeles- 2','Dallas -1','Dallas - 2','Dallas3']})

print (df1)

#create a column to compare both dataframes. Remove numeric, - and space values
df1['Place_compare'] = df1.Place.str.replace('\d+|-| ', '')


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Place':['New York','Los Angeles','Dallas 1'],
                    'target':[1000,1500,2000],
                    'value1':['a','c','e'],
                    'value2':['b','d','f']})

print (df2)

#create a column to compare both dataframes. Remove numeric, - and space values
df2['Place_compare'] = df2.Place.str.replace('\d+|-| ', '')

#count number of times the unique values of Place occurs in df1. assign to df2
df2['counts'] = df2['Place_compare'].map(df1['Place_compare'].value_counts())

#calculate new target based on number of occurrences of Place in df1
df2['new_target'] = (df2['target'] / df2['counts']).round(2)

#repeat the nows by the number of times it appears in counts
df2 = df2.reindex(df2.index.repeat(df2['counts']))

#drop temp columns
df2.drop(['counts','Place_compare','target'], axis=1, inplace=True)

#rename new_target as target
df2 = df2.rename({'new_target': 'target'}, axis=1)
print (df2)
```

The output of this will be:

Dataframe1:

```
            Place
0        New York
1   Los Angeles 1
2  Los Angeles- 2
3       Dallas -1
4      Dallas - 2
5         Dallas3
```

Dataframe2:

```
         Place  target value1 value2
0     New York    1000      a      b
1  Los Angeles    1500      c      d
2     Dallas 1    2000      e      f
```

Updated DataFrame with repeated values:

```
         Place value1 value2  target
0     New York      a      b  1000.00
1  Los Angeles      c      d   750.00
1  Los Angeles      c      d   750.00
2     Dallas 1      e      f   666.67
2     Dallas 1      e      f   666.67
2     Dallas 1      e      f   666.67
```